# Second Child Value Check in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV like below:

```
<div class="metafield_table">
   <div class="metafield"></div>
   <div class="metafield"></div>
   <div class="metafield"></div>
</div>
```

Here, `metafield` will be variable. It could be one, two and many times. I want to check Second Child has or not.

With jQuery how to do this?

My try:

```
var secondChild = $('.metafield_table .metafield:nth-child(2)').val;
  if(!secondChild) {
    $('.metafield').css({'width': '100%'});
  }
  else {
    $('.metafield').css({'width': '50%'});
  }
```

If I have one `metafield` then there is no Second Child. But it is always going to `else` condition!!!

Comment: where is class `speci_wrap`?, also `val` should be `val()`

Comment: Of course it is, because `.val` makes no sense. It would need to be `.val()` to get the value from an input field, but for the content of a div it is completely wrong to begin with. If you want to get the content, then you are probably looking for `.text()`. (Unclear what you actually want, with _“I want to check Second Child has or not.”_ - speaking in complete sentences could help.)

Comment: Sorry it will be `metafield`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your selector is correct, you can check the existing of the element like so:

```
var secondChild = $('.metafield_table .speci_wrap:nth-child(2)');

if(secondChild[0]){
  // element exists
}else{
  // element does not exist
}
```

Comment: I read the question like: `how to check element-existence of second child?` And I´m checking existence of jquery-selected-elements for over a decade like this and it always worked and never failed silently ;)

Comment: Yes. I want to check the existence of second child.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;

$('.metafield').each(function() {
  num++;
});


if (num > 1) {
  $('.speci_wrap').css({
    'width': '100%'
  });
} else {
  $('.speci_wrap').css({
    'width': '50%'
  });
}
```